# Exactly-once-delivery and in-sequence-delivery with MassTransit on MSMQ

Tags: design-patterns, msmq, masstransit

Using MassTransit on MSMQ can we automatically support *exactly-once-delivery* (e.g., when an event store publishes events twice) and *in-sequence-delivery* (e.g., when two nodes concurrently write/publish events, it is possible that node A stores event #2, then node B reads event #2, node B stores event #3, node B publishes event #3, node A publishes event #2 - a typical race condition)?

And if MassTransit does not support that out of the box (which I am currently assuming), what is the best/common approach to implement these two requirements with MassTransit/MSMQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MassTransit follows [Actor model's no guarantees for order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model#No_requirement_on_order_of_message_arrival) of message delivery. It does however have [Sagas](https://masstransit.readthedocs.org/en/master/overview/saga.html) to help with arbitrary handling of order. You may also consider implementing your consumers as [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indempotency#Computer_science_meaning).